# Array.indexOf throws errors in some IE versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, internet-explorer

IE7 and IE8 are not letting me splice my array (Safari, Chrome, Firefox work):

```
        lzaCreateAd1.weatherArray = new Array();
        var jWeatherIcon = $('.weatherIcon');

        jWeatherIcon.bind('click', function (){
            var targetID = $(this).attr('id') + 'Box',
            idVal = targetID.substr(5,1);

            var jTargetBox = $('#'+targetID);

            if (jTargetBox.hasClass('inactive')) {
                jTargetBox.removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
                lzaCreateAd1.weatherArray.push(idVal);
            } else if (jTargetBox.hasClass('active')) {
                jTargetBox.removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
                lzaCreateAd1.weatherArray.splice(lzaCreateAd1.weatherArray.indexOf(idVal),1);
            }
        });
```

IE throws the following error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" for this line:

`lzaCreateAd1.weatherArray.splice(lzaCreateAd1.weatherArray.indexOf(idVal),1);`

Any ideas?  Or other ways to remove an array item by value?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is not supported by Internet Explorer before version 9. You can use the jQuery's `$.inArray` utility function, or any other shim/polyfill you want instead.

```
lzaCreateAd1.weatherArray.splice($.inArray(idVal, lzaCreateAd1.weatherArray) ,1);
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: Yet ANOTHER reason why IE is the bane of many a web-devloper's existence. Thanks!